# Accidentally I've formatted my home folder, can I fix it?

Tags: 16.04

The story is I accidentally formatted my home folder, I was thinking it was my USB drive. After I restart my computer, it show Grub menu : 
[image]

Then I clicked on Ubuntu, it showed Emergency Window :

[image]

I don't really know what to do, I've been searching for the solution all day. I tried some tutorials there, but it cannot solve mine.

Is there a chance to fix this whitout reinstall my Ubuntu ?

Comment: I'd guess you only need to change the `/etc/fstab` entry for your /home entry to match the new UUID for your drive. Your data will be gone, and it was my booboo I'd probably add a new user (at terminal)so I could see what effects logging in with a blank userdir & home directory has before I tried it on my own account/id.  If it looked ok, then I'd create a your user-dir (maybe copying in [with `chown` etc] files from the temp-test-user directory to your wanted userid-user-dir).  but this is theory as I don't recall doing this before

Comment: Data will have to be recovered using recovery tools, e.g. testdisk. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: I have create a new user before. To be honest, I don't have important files there.

Comment: @Takkat .. my system can't install any software

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution: you have to do that from a live session anyway (boot the installer in *"try out Ubuntu"* mode) but if there are no important data a reinstall may be the fastest way to get Ubuntu back.